# How to find the surface area of unit cube using a surface integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**Problem:**

Consider the vector field $F=z\hat{i}+y\hat{j}+x\hat{k}$, and $S$ the *unit* cube.

[image: unit cube]

Find $\int_S\ F\cdot dS$

**Solution:**

I have used the *divergence theorem:*

$\iint_S\ \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{S}=\iiint_S\ \text{div}\vec{F}\ dV$

So, for the vector field $F$ the diverge is $1$.

Then the triple integral behaves:

$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} dxdydz=1$

Does the way I have used the divergence theorem is correct? I think the result is incorrect because the sum of each cube side is greater than 1.

Comment: Well, each face has area 1 and there are 6 faces so you should get $6$.